# Cytoscape js - Remove nodes in collection from memory

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

Need a hand with removing a collection from memory with cytoscape js.  My use case is I am trying to prefilter large graphs so that before the visualisation is rendered I can reduce the amount of data that is being presented.  My code is something like this so far.  The documentation clearly states that cy.remove does not remove from memory.  I have tried `cy.removeData(element_del)` and even an `element_del.forEach` to remove the data to make the items disappear but no luck.

```
var preFilter = "nodeIWantToStartFrom"
// If the prefilter variable exists with a valid field 
if (preFilter) {

              if (preFilter.length > 0) {
                // Search for the node in a prebuilt dictionary
                if (nodesByName[preFilter].id) {
                  node_id = "#" + nodesByName[preFilter].id;
                  highlightCollection = cy.collection(cy.elements().bfs(node_id, 1, directedPathFind).path);
                  var element_del = cy.elements().not(cy.$(highlightCollection));
                  // Remove elements
                 cy.remove(element_del);
                  })
                }
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

All you can control is whether a reference can be removed by the garbage collector.